# ¿Como usar timeago (o cualquier componente vue) en page de Quasar?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estoy buscando la manera de hacer un 'tiempo transcurrido' para el frontend de una aplicacion de mensajeria (en Quasar) de manera que salgan los mensajes como por ejemplo "Enviado por Jaimito hace 5 minutos".

Investigue e encontre que existe el componente `timeago` e intente seguir al pie de la letra las instrucciones de https://vuejsfeed.com/blog/vue-timeago-timeago-component-for-vue-js pero lo mas próximo a lo que pude llegar fue a importar el componente de una forma parecida a esta:

```
import VueTimeago from 'vue-timeago'
export default {
  name: 'PageIndex'
  ,created() {
    this.time = Date.now()
  }
  ,components: {
    'timeago': VueTimeago
  }
}
```

Y a utilizarlo dentro del html de la forma:

```
<timeago :since="time"></timeago>
```

tampoco me ha servido con:

```
<timeago :datetime="datetime"></timeago>
```

En cuanto al error no sale, simplemente no aparece nada.

Lo estoy ejecutando dentro de una pagina de Quasar en un SPA

Comment: prueba con la libreria base https://github.com/hustcc/timeago.js